# SQL Case in one row

Tags: sql, case

i have a problem with case, i need to see my results in one row (see attachment), thanks for any help.

My code:

```
select a_number as "Number",
       sum(case when code1 in ('CHOR1')   then d_left end) as "Absence",
       sum(case when code2 in ('KKK') then d_left end) as "KKK",
       sum(case when code2 in ('PPP') then d_left end) as "PPP"
```

THanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Your query is in complete.  It will not run without a `from` clause, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Just use "group by "

```
select a_number as "Number", sum(case when code1 in ('CHOR1') then d_left end) as "Absence", sum(case when code2 in ('KKK') then d_left end) as "KKK", sum(case when code2 in ('PPP') then d_left end) as "PPP"
group by a_number
```

Comment: Maybe your data in Number columns are not same(have space?) Try change a_number to  TRIM(a_number).